# Jenkins + AWS agent = error only in php-project's job, Java-projects' jobs work fine: /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, docker, jenkins, continuous-integration

How to fix this?

Here is my error:

```
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.40/auth: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

***!!! This failure only in php-project's job, Java-projects' jobs work fine. !!!***

Check, please, also used configuration:

```
dockerhub_private = '5555555555.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com'

pipeline {
    options {
        durabilityHint 'PERFORMANCE_OPTIMIZED'

        buildDiscarder logRotator(daysToKeepStr: '6', numToKeepStr: '30')
    }
    agent {
        label 'ec2spot-t3large-php74'
    }

    parameters {
        booleanParam(name: 'UPDATE_DOCKER_IMAGES', defaultValue: true, description: 'Update Docker images?')
    }

    stages {
        stage('Base Docker') {
            when {
                beforeAgent true
                anyOf {
                    expression { params.UPDATE_DOCKER_IMAGES }
                }
            }
            steps {
                script {
                    GIT_COMMIT = sh(script: 'git rev-parse HEAD', returnStdout: true).trim()
                    GIT_BRANCH = sh(script: 'git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD', returnStdout: true).trim()
                }

                sh "df -h"

                withAWS(credentials: 'JENKINS_AWS_ACCESS', region: 'eu-west-1') {
                    sh ecrLogin()
                }

                withCredentials([
                    usernamePassword(
                        credentialsId: 'DOCKERHUB_company_',
                        usernameVariable: 'DOCKER_USERNAME',
                        passwordVariable: 'DOCKER_PASSWORD'
                    )
                ]) {
                    sh "docker login -u $DOCKER_USERNAME -p $DOCKER_PASSWORD"
                }

                pullFromPublicAndPushToPrivate([
                    'external/php'
                ], params.UPDATE_DOCKER_IMAGES)

                sh """
                    docker logout; \\
                    df -h; \\
                    docker info; \\
                    top -b -n1 -o %MEM; \\
                    docker images | grep company_r;
                  """
            }

             post {
                 unsuccessful {
                     slackSend tokenCredentialId: 'slack_y_core_team_token', color: 'danger',
                               teamDomain: 'company-it', channel: '#x_team_ci',
                               message: "DOCKER PULL FAILED: <${BUILD_URL}|${BUILD_ID}>, branch: ${env.GIT_BRANCH}"
                 }
             }
        }

        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                 githubNotify status: 'PENDING', description: "BUILD $BUILD_ID has started", context: 'jenkins/build',
                              targetUrl: "$BUILD_URL", credentialsId: 'company_msbot',
                              account: 'company', repo: 'y_php_project', sha: "${env.GIT_COMMIT}"
                sh """
                    echo RELEASE_VERSION=`date +"%Y%m%d"`-r$BUILD_NUMBER; \\
                    echo REVISION=$RELEASE_VERSION; \\
                    echo DOCKER_HOST=tcp://localhost:4243; \\
                    echo $REVISION>$WORKSPACE/nginx/version.html; \\
                    echo IMAGE_NAME=company_r/cx-y_php_project; \\

                    cd $WORKSPACE; \\
                    docker build -t $IMAGE_NAME:$REVISION .; \\

                    docker push $IMAGE_NAME:$REVISION; \\
                    docker tag  $IMAGE_NAME:$REVISION $IMAGE_NAME:latest; \\
                    docker push $IMAGE_NAME:latest; \\

                    PUSH_RETRY_COUNT=15; \\
                    PUSH_RETRY_DELAY=30; \\
                    retry "docker push $IMAGE_NAME:latest" $PUSH_RETRY_COUNT $PUSH_RETRY_DELAY; \\
                    docker tag  $IMAGE_NAME:latest $IMAGE_NAME:$REVISION; \\
                    retry "docker push $IMAGE_NAME:$REVISION" $PUSH_RETRY_COUNT $PUSH_RETRY_DELAY; \\
                    #remove old images; \\
                    set +e; \\
                    docker images | grep "^<none>" | awk '{system("docker rmi -f "\$3)}'; \\
                    docker images | grep $IMAGE_NAME | grep -v "minute" | grep -v "second" | awk '{system("docker rmi -f "\$3)}'; \\
                    set -e; \\
                """
                sh script: 'sar -A', label: 'System Stats'
            }

            post {
                success {
                    githubNotify status: 'SUCCESS', description: "BUILD $BUILD_ID has finished", context: 'jenkins/build',
                                 targetUrl: "$BUILD_URL", credentialsId: 'company_msbot',
                                 account: 'company', repo: 'y_php_project', sha: "${env.GIT_COMMIT}"
                    slackSend tokenCredentialId: 'slack_y_core_team_token',
                            teamDomain: 'company-it', channel: '#x_team_ci',
                            message: "BUILD SUCCED: <${BUILD_URL}|${BUILD_ID}>, branch: ${env.GIT_BRANCH}"
                }

                unsuccessful {
                    githubNotify status: 'ERROR', description: "BUILD $BUILD_ID has failed", context: 'jenkins/build',
                                 targetUrl: "$BUILD_URL", credentialsId: 'company_msbot',
                                 account: 'company', repo: 'y_php_project', sha: "${env.GIT_COMMIT}"

                    slackSend tokenCredentialId: 'slack_y_core_team_token', color: 'danger',
                              teamDomain: 'company-it', channel: '#x_team_ci',
                              message: "BUILD FAILED: <${BUILD_URL}|${BUILD_ID}>, branch: ${env.GIT_BRANCH}"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

def getNameInPrivate(image) {
    if (image.startsWith('company_r/')) {
        image
    } else {
        "external/${image.split('/')[-1]}"
    }
}

void pullFromPublicAndPushToPrivate(images, updateFromPublic) {
    for (image in images) {
        def private_image = getNameInPrivate(image)

        sh script: """\
              docker pull ${dockerhub_private}/${private_image} &&
                docker tag ${dockerhub_private}/${private_image} ${image};
              ECR_PULL_CODE=\$?;
              if [ "\$ECR_PULL_CODE" != "0" ] || [ "${updateFromPublic}" = "true" ]
              then
                docker pull ${image}; \\
                docker tag ${image} ${dockerhub_private}/${private_image}; \\
                docker push ${dockerhub_private}/${private_image};
              fi
            """.stripIndent(), label: "Pull & Push ${image}"
    }
}
```

I will provide Dockerfile also

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm

COPY composer.lock composer.json /var/www/

WORKDIR /var/www

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    mariadb-client \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    locales \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    vim \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl

RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring zip exif pcntl
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ --with-png-dir=/usr/include/
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

RUN groupadd -g 1000 www
RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www www

COPY . /var/www

RUN composer install

COPY docker/start.sh /usr/local/bin/start
RUN chmod 777 /usr/local/bin/start

RUN chown www:www /var/www

RUN chown -R www:www-data storage
RUN chown -R www:www-data bootstrap/cache
RUN chmod -R 775 storage
RUN chmod -R 775 bootstrap/cache

USER www

EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["/usr/local/bin/start"]
```

What should be mentioned else?

Maybe, plugins? But looks like issue is only for this job.

Or sever configuration / version.

Answer (score 0):

The error says that your current user can’t access the docker engine, because you’re lacking permissions to access the unix socket to communicate with the engine.
In order to solve this issue :
Run below command in any of your shell:
`sudo usermod -a -G docker $USER`
`sudo usermod -a -G docker jenkins`
**NOTE** : do a complete restart of machine and also jenkins.
After this step : Completely log out of your account and log back in.

For more info : https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/

Comment: no( other jobs are fine, so lack of permissions is not the issue